# Sum a variable over all threads in a CUDA Kernel and return it to Host

Tags: cuda, gpu

I new in cuda and I'm try to implement a Kernel to calculate the energy of my Metropolis Monte Carlo Simulation.

I'll put here the linear version of this function:

```
float calc_energy(struct frame frm, float L, float rc){
int i,j;
float E=0, rij, dx, dy, dz;
for(i=0; i<frm.natm; i++)
{
    for(j=i+1; j<frm.natm; j++)
    {
        dx = fabs(frm.conf[j][0] - frm.conf[i][0]);
        dy = fabs(frm.conf[j][1] - frm.conf[i][1]);
        dz = fabs(frm.conf[j][2] - frm.conf[i][2]);
        dx = dx - round(dx/L)*L;
        dy = dy - round(dy/L)*L;
        dz = dz - round(dz/L)*L;

        /*rij*/
        rij = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);

        if (rij <= rc)
        {
            E = E + (4*((1/pow(rij,12))-(1/pow(rij,6))));
        }
    } 
}

return E;
```

Then I'm try to parallelize this using Cuda: This is my idea:

```
void calc_energy(frame* s, float L, float rc)
{

extern __shared__ float E;

int i = blockDim.x*blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x; 
int j = blockDim.y*blockIdx.y + threadIdx.y; 

float rij, dx, dy, dz;

dx = fabs(s->conf[j][0] - s->conf[i][0]);
dy = fabs(s->conf[j][1] - s->conf[i][1]);
dz = fabs(s->conf[j][2] - s->conf[i][2]);
dx = dx - round(dx/L)*L;
dy = dy - round(dy/L)*L;
dz = dz - round(dz/L)*L; 

rij = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy + dz*dz);

if (rij <= rc)
{
   E += (4*((1/pow(rij,12))-(1/pow(rij,6)))); //<- here is the big problem
}
}
```

My main question is how to sum the variable E from each thread and return it to the host??. I intend to use as many thread and blocks as possible.

Obviously a part of the code is missing when the variable E is calculated.

I have read a few things about reduction methods, but I would like to know if this is necessary here.

I call the kernel using the following code:

```
 calc_energy<<<dimGrid,dimBlock>>>(d_state, 100, 5);
```

**edit**:

I understood that I needed to use reduction methods. [CUB](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/index.html) work great to me.

Continuing with the implementation of the code, I realized that I have a new problem, perhaps because of my lack of knowledge in this area.

In my nested loop, the variable (`frm.natm`) can reach values in the order of 10^5. thinking of my GPU (GTX 750ti) the number of Thread per block is 1024 and the number of Block per grid is 1024. If I understood correctly, the maximum number of runs in a kernel is 1024x1024 = 1048576 (less than that actually).

So if I need to do 10^5 x 10^5 = 10^10 calculations in my nested loop, what would be the best way to think of the algorithm? Choose a fixed number (that fits my GPU) and split the calculations would be a good idea?

Comment: Yes, a reduction method is necessary here.  You can use atomics or a [classical parallel reduction](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/1.1-Beta/x86_website/projects/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf).  Both methods are covered extensively in numerous other questions here on the `cuda` tag.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I implemented the CUB algorithm and it worked very well! I had a new question, so I edited my initial question, if you could help me I would be very grateful.

Comment: The maximum number of threads per block is 1024, yes.  The maximum number of blocks per grid is not 1024.  For GTX 750ti, single dimensional grid, it is (2^31)-1.  Therefore a single-dimensional grid could have over 10^12 threads.   But as you point out, you can run with a smaller grid and place a loop in your code to handle multiple data points.  A concept like this (grid-stride loop) is covered in [this blog](https://devblogs.nvidia.com/cuda-pro-tip-write-flexible-kernels-grid-stride-loops/).

Comment: 2^31-1 wow!!! in my case I intend use 2 dimensional block, like a grid dim3 = dimgrid(1024,1024). I will test and return. Thanks again, Robert

Answer (score 2):

> My main question is how to sum the variable E from each thread and return it to the host?

You will need to sum each threads calculation at a *block* level first using some form of block-wise parallel reduction (I recommend the [CUB block wise reduction implementation](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/classcub_1_1_block_reduce.html) for that).

Once each block has a partial sum from its threads, the block sums need to be combined. This can either be done on the atomically by one thread from each block, by a second kernel call (with one block), or on the host. How and where you will use the final sum will determine which of those options is the most optimal for your application.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/generate.h>
#include <thrust/reduce.h>
#include <thrust/functional.h>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>

int main(void)
{
    thrust::host_vector<int> h_vec(100);
    std::generate(h_vec.begin(), h_vec.end(), rand);

    thrust::device_vector<int> d_vec = h_vec;
    int x = thrust::reduce(d_vec.begin(), d_vec.end(), 0, thrust::plus<int>());
    std::cout<< x<< std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```